# Async DNS resolving with I/O Completion Ports, is it possible?

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, dns, iocp

If I want to do DNS resolving, could I do that with I/O Completion Ports?
I have made a search, and it seems I could do that with 2 methods:

---

1) using `GetAddrInfoEx()` [?]

2) implementing DNS parsing by myself (that is, a little DNS client)

---

I wanted more info on the first, using `GetAddrInfoEx()`, is that possible using it in I/O Completion Ports, in the meaning that I/O Completion Ports threads receive requests (OVERLAPPED) of completed DNS queries? The MSDN page [1] didn't tell nothing about I/O Completion Ports on this API, indeed, how it can receive those OVERLAPPEDs if using `GetAddrInfoEx()` doesn't involve the use of any HANDLE, to associate with the I/O Completion Port?

The second method is more straightforward, you have an UDP (or even TCP) socket that you could associate with I/O Completion Ports, and you implement a little client for DNS resolving, or you can use a library such as ldns [2] to only parse the DNS query, and not doing the real I/O, which will be done by your UDP socket and your I/O Completion Port.
Anyone used this latter method?

---

[1] [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738518(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[2] http://www.nlnetlabs.nl/projects/ldns/

Comment: The lack of being able to associate an open handle with an IOCP would seem to put the former of these out of the realm of options. You seem to have forgone simply using async-overlapped IO and a completion *routine*, which GetAddrInfoEx does support, and may be the simplest of all of your possible options. But as far as IOCP is concerned, I don't see it unless you pursue your second option. I never thought of this before either, so interesting question.

Comment: Thanks! Well, I'm of course aware of the `GetAddrInfoEx()` completion routine, but it won't be able to be used inside the I/O Completion Port's threads. Unless, maybe, you set a global completion routine called when a DNS query is resolved, which in turn puts an user-defined completion to the I/O Completion Port. This latter method should work pretty well. I have to try it :) Just come up to mind right now.

Comment: Thats a helluva good idea. Having your completion routine post a message via [`PostQueuedCompletionStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365458(v=vs.85).aspx) with an appropriately detectable completion key and LPOVERLAPPED param (which can be anything) would be a pretty elegant solution if you just want everything handled in the IOCP thread pools. Nice idea.

Comment: Personally I'd go for option 2, do the DNS lookup yourself. The problem with using a completion routine is that this requires a thread to be in an alertable wait state for it to be called and even if you set that up you then have the additional context switch required if you pass the result off to your I/O pool. With a custom DNS client you can do all of the work on your I/O threads and avoid any additional threads and/or context switches.

Comment: Thanks Len, I totally agree with this, I was only scared about the complexity of the protocol, but using support libraries that does the effective parsing (such as ldns), that shouldn't be too much work. May I ask you what method you choosen for the Server Framework?

Comment: For The Server Framework I decided on option 2. I've yet to have a client that actually needed it so it's still an open JIRA ticket.

Comment: Did you solve the problem Marco?

Comment: Hello Janus, this is a problem I worked out many years ago. At the end I had a tiny DNS protocol client, which sent DNS queries manually, using TCP or UDP with normal IOCPs.